# Does query_posts have an effect on get_the_category?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I am having trouble debugging a situation, and I think some better background information on how these systems work would be very helpful. I know that the use of the function `query_posts` is strongly discouraged. But let's just assume that there is nothing I can do to remove it from the code. Specifically the query is changed to pull posts of a post_type (a `post_type` specific to the theme I am using). This is what the query looks like after it has been changed:

```
posts_per_page=10&paged=0&post_type=project
```

Then the loop begins and it can successfully grab the titles for each post. But when I call `get_the_category` it returns an empty array, even though all of the posts have categories. I verified that it was an empty array with `var_dump`.

I do not have a strong understanding of how these systems work, so the emphasis on not using `query_posts` has me worried. Is there any possible interaction between `query_posts` and `get_the_category` that could cause it to not work correctly?

Comment: Since this is a custom post type, does it have a custom taxonomy or is it actually **the** `category` tax? And would you mind sharing why exactly you can not do what you want by using `WP_Query`?

Comment: Ahh, I am not sure about that, but from the admin dashboard the categories are listed under the same section as the project posts, they aren't listed under the normal posts.  Does that mean these are custom categories?

Comment: Well, if there is a new submenu entry for these categories then it's most likely a custom taxonomy. The name/slug of the tax will be stated in the URL if you click to edit the categories. Then just use `get_the_terms` for that taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

The "main" query on the page is saved to a `global` called `$wp_query`. That `global` determines a great deal about the page, including both content and which template is used to display that content. Using `$wp_query` overwrites that main query and can cause some very basic things to fail but `get_the_category()` is probably not one of them.

It is more likely that there is something wrong with your Loop. What matters for `get_the_category()` is another `global` called `$post`. `$post` is set at each iteration of a proper Loop to the "current post". If `get_the_category()` is not passed a post ID, it will assume that `$post` is the post in question.

Without seeing the code, that is the best I've got.